# react native use variable for image file

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I know that to use a static image in react native you need to do a require to that image specifically, but I am trying to load a random image based on a number. For example I have 100 images called img1.png - img100.png in my directory. I am trying to figure out a way to  do the following

```
<Image source={require(`./img${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}.png`)}/>
```

I know this intentionally does not work, but any workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried implementing this? I am unable to understand why this wouldn't work, as long as your file path to the image exists. Since RN0.14, you can directly require images from image paths, so this method should work

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 127):

For anyone getting to know the react-native beast, this should help :)

I visited a couple of sites in the past too, but found it increasingly frustrating. Until I read [this site here](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/react-native-tips-and-tricks-2-0-managing-static-assets-with-absolute-paths/).

It's a different approach but it eventually does pay off in the end.
Basically, the best approach would be to load all your resources in one place.
Consider the following structure

```
app  
   |--img
      |--image1.jpg
      |--image2.jpg
      |--profile
          |--profile.png
          |--comments.png
      |--index.js
```

In `index.js`, you can do this:

```
const images = {
    profile: {
        profile: require('./profile/profile.png'),
        comments: require('./profile/comments.png'),
    },
    image1: require('./image1.jpg'),
    image2: require('./image2.jpg'),
};

export default images;
```

In your views, you have to import the images component like this:

```
import Images from './img/index';

render() {
    <Image source={Images.profile.comments} />
}
```

Everybody has different means to an end, just pick the one that suits you best.

**Da Man - Q: How is this answer using a variable?**

Well, since `require` only accepts a literal string, you can't use variables, concatenated strings, etc. This is the next best thing. Yes, it still is a lot of work, but now you can do something resembling the OP's question:

```
render() {
  var images = { test100: "image100" };
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
       test {images["test" + "100"]}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much!

Comment: Just curious, does this mean every image is loaded into memory when the user hits the view and does this happen every time?

Comment: @Aaron No, there's a difference between loading and rendering. These images are only rendered when you use them (something called lazy loading). See this as a bag of hooks. the actual rendering happens here: `<Image source={Images.profile.comments} />`

Comment: Thank you. I used this implementation and I really like it.

Comment: If only we had a more native solution like Android has :/

Comment: How does this method use variable ? You are still specifying which image to load.

Comment: @DerpyNerd Is there any way to provide the key like this: first image, with a space in between the name?

Comment: @bubble-cord Are you talking about keys like "test 001"? In that case; yes. `{"test 001": "<imgurl>"}` is a valid js object and so is getting the keys' value using `images["test 001"]`

Answer (score 59):

In JS require statements are resolved at bundle time (when the JS bundle is calculated). Therefore it's not supported to put variable expression as an argument for `require`.

In case of requiring resources it's even more trickier. When you have `require('./someimage.png')`, React Native packager will locale required image and it will be then bundled together with the app so that it can be used as a "static" resource when your app is running (in fact in dev mode it won't bundle the image with your app but instead the image will be served from the server, but this doesn't matter in your case).

If you want to use random image as a static resource you'd need to tell your app to bundle that image. You can do it in a few ways:

1) Add it as a static asset of your app, then reference to it with `<Image src={{uri:'name_of_the_image_in_assets.png'}}/>` ([here](http://www.idev101.com/learn/adding_images.html) is how you can add it to the native iOS app)

2) Require all the images upfront statically. Sth in a form of:

```
var randomImages = [
    require('./image1.png'),
    require('./image2.png'),
    require('./image3.png'),
    ...
];
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
<Image src={randomImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImages.length)]}/>
```

3) Use network image with `<Image src={{uri:'http://i.imgur.com/random.jpg'}}/>`

Comment: what if you had a thousand images named image1.png, image2.png, image3.png etc - it's seems really odd that require won't accept a variable path and that you can't write a loop to create that randomImages array. Wouldn't one to be forced to write a thousand lines?! If I try to pass a variable into the require line, it complain the module is not found.

Comment: what to do if list is coming from api ?

Comment: This solved my issue for me. I was trying to dynamically create the links in a function and return that require(<variablePath>) to the image source and was having continual errors. Great work!

Answer (score 7):

```
class ImageContainer extends Component {
   this.state ={
     image:require('default-img')
   }
    <View>
           <Image source={this.state.image} />
    </View>
}
```

In the context of this discussion,I had this case where wanted to dynamically assign images for a particular background. Here I change state like this

```
this.setState({
  image:require('new-image')
})
```

Comment: This is a good start. Can you add how it solves the problem? A little description of what your code does would be nice.

Comment: Inside require, if I have to use the dynamic image then how to do it ? ex:    image:require(this.index+".png") where index = 1 initially.

Comment: The text in the require can be exchanged for state or props, take note that the purpose for the example above was for retrieving local images, for external images i.e "http://image.png" the syntax structure would change to <Image source={{ uri: externalImage}}>

Answer (score 3):

I came to this thread looking for a way to add images in a dynamic way. I quickly found that passing in a variable to the Image -> require() was not working.

Thanks to DerpyNerd for getting me on the correct path.

After implementing the resources in one place I then found it easy to add the Images. But, I still needed a way to dynamically assign these images based on changing state in my application.

I created a function that would accept a string from a state value and would then return the Image that matched that string logically.

**Setup**

Image structure:

```
app  
  |--src
    |--assets
      |--images
        |--logos
          |--small_kl_logo.png
          |--small_a1_logo.png
          |--small_kc_logo.png
          |--small_nv_logo.png
          |--small_other_logo.png

        |--index.js
    |--SearchableList.js
```

In `index.js`, I have this:

```
const images = {
  logos: {
    kl: require('./logos/small_kl_logo.png'),
    a1: require('./logos/small_a1_logo.png'),
    kc: require('./logos/small_kc_logo.png'),
    nv: require('./logos/small_nv_logo.png'),
    other: require('./logos/small_other_logo.png'),
  }
};

export default images;
```

In my `SearchableList.js` component, I then imported the Images component like this:

```
import Images from './assets/images';
```

I then created a new function `imageSelect` in my component:

```
imageSelect = network => {
  if (network === null) {
    return Images.logos.other;
  }

  const networkArray = {
    'KL': Images.logos.kl,
    'A1': Images.logos.a1,
    'KC': Images.logos.kc,
    'NV': Images.logos.nv,
    'Other': Images.logos.other,
  };

  return networkArray[network];
};
```

Then in my components `render` function I call this new `imageSelect` function to dynamically assign the desired Image based on the value in the `this.state.network`:

```
render() {
  <Image source={this.imageSelect(this.state.network)} />
}
```

Once again, thanks to DerpyNerd for getting me on the correct path. I hope this answer helps others. :)

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things here. There is no need for the `imageSelect` function. Because `images` is a simple javascript object, you can dynamically call the keys in that object. e.g. `<Image source={Images.logos[this.state.network]} />`. Just make sure they keys match with the possible network states :)

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a simple and truly dynamic solution(no renaming or import required) to the problem if you have a bigger no of files.**

*[Won't work for Expo Managed]*

*Although the question is old I think this is the simpler solution and might be helpful. But I beg a pardon for any terminological mistakes, correct me please if I do any.*

INSTEAD OF USING **REQUIRE** WE CAN USE THE **URI** WITH **NATIVE APP ASSETS** FOR ANDROID (AND/OR iOS). **HERE WE WILL DISCUSS ABOUT ANDROID ONLY**

*URI can easily be manipulated as per the requirement but normally it's used for network/remote assets only but works for local and native assets too. Whereas require can not be used for dynamic file names and dirs*

**STEPS**

1. Open `android/app/src/main/assets` folder from your `App.js` or `index.js` containing directory, if the `assets` folder doesn't exist create one.
2. Make a folder named `images` or any `NAME` of your choice inside `assets`, and paste all the images there.
3. Create a file named `react-native.config.js` in the main app folder containing `App.js` or `index.js`.
4. Add these lines to the new js file:

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/'],
};
```

at the place of `YOUR_FOLDER_NAME` use the newly created folder's name `images` or any given `NAME`

5. Now run `npx react-native link` in your terminal from main app folder, this will link/add the assets folder in the android bundle. Then rebuild the debug app.
6. From now on you can access all the files from inside `android/app/src/main/assets` in your react-native app.
   For example:

```
<Image
   style={styles.ImageStyle}
   source={{ uri: 'asset:/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/img' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '.png' }}
/>
```

Comment: It does not work

Comment: Should work except for Expo Managed version if followed. I do not actively work on RN if anybody can confirm especially people who upvoted.