# How can you dynamically change the source in a require statement that requires an image file?

Tags: javascript, react-native

The image I'm using in React Native uses a require statement for the source of the image. I want to change the source of the image so it is kind of of like switching out frames in an animation.

```
var module1 = './hello';
var module2 = './goodbye';

state = {
  module: module1 // will later be changed to module2
}

require(this.state.module);
```

Comment: why would you want to change a required module? do they implement the same functions? then get rid of one of the modules and introduce a flag to the functions to change their behavior dynamically.

Comment: I have an image that I want to replace the source of to animate by switching out the 'frames'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating an object like this:

`var frames = {
    '1': require('./assets/phase1.png'),
    '2': require('./assets/phase2.png'),
    '3': require('./assets/phase3.png'),
    '4': require('./assets/phase4.png'),
}`

and in my Image tag, I set the `source` attribute to `this.state.frame` and setState with a new key from frames like `frames[imageIndex]`.  Luckily I didn't have too many images, but this isn't the most ideal solution.

EDIT:
Another solution (which is more elegant and less verbose) is to create a drawable folder in android>app>src>main>res and drop all the images in the that folder.  On iOS, you can drop all your images in ios>Appname>Images.xcassets.

From there, you can set the source of your images to `{uri: this.state.imageFile}` where `this.state.imageFile` is a string without the file extension and you can change them dynamically without having to `require()` each file.

Comment: why do you require all images? why not create an array `frames = ['./assets/phase1.png', './assets/phase2.png', './assets/phase3.png', ...]` and then just `require(frames[this.state.frame])`? or if your image naming is like this, even easier: `require('./assets/phase' + this.state.frame + '.png')`

Comment: Because that didn't work for some reason.  I was not able to require(<variable>)

Comment: Just tried this in node.js and it worked: `var module = 'fs';` and `var fs = require(module);` I don't know what react does when requiring an image though...

Comment: Probably because when you require an image file, there is no module.exports, or export default.  I'll change the question title to be Image centric.

Comment: That shouldn't have anything to do with how the string is passed to the `require()`. It is valid Javascript. Anyway it's a good idea to make it clear it's about requiring images.

Comment: "Note that in order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically."  Facebook confirms my instinct. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources

Comment: found an explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33917557/2897426 ... react creates a bundle of your scripts & assets, so require statements are resolved at bundle time and you can't use variable expressions as arguments.

Comment: Just edited my answer so that you can just use the file name instead of having to require each image.

Answer (score 0):

Require both and then use the correct one where you need it:

```
var hello = require('./hello');
var goodbye = require('./goodbye');

hello.myFunction();

// later:

goodbye.anotherFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is a good programming style but it is possible.
For example the modules look like this

```
exports.name = () => {
  console.log('modul1')
}
```

And the main file like this, it will work like expected

```
const modul1 = './modul1'
const modul2 = './modul2'

var modul = require(modul1)
modul.name() // -> modul1
modul = require(modul2)
modul.name() // -> modul2
```