# Setting source of <Image/> with variable

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I am trying some react native code which is as follows , I want to set the static images to an image view as follows but it doesn't load

```js
const items = [
            { name: './images/home.png', code: '#1abc9c' }, { name: './images/home.png', code: '#2ecc71' },
            { name: './images/home.png', code: '#3498db' }, { name: './images/home.png', code: '#9b59b6' }
        ];

        return (
            <ImageBackground
                source={require('./images/marble.jpg')}
                style={styles.backgroundImage}>

                <GridView
                    itemDimension={130}
                    items={items}
                    style={styles.gridView}
                    renderItem={item => (
                        <View style={[styles.itemContainer, { backgroundColor: item.code }]}>
                            <Image source={require(item.name)}></Image>
                        </View>
                    )}
                />

            </ImageBackground>
        );
```

Error I get is

> calls to `require` expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found: `require(item.name)`.

Ofcourse I am new to react native so kindly ignore my missed terminology

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react native use variable for image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907218/react-native-use-variable-for-image-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try like this

```
const items = [{ name: require('./images/home.png'), code: '#1abc9c' },{...}]
```

then

```
<Image source={item.name}></Image>
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that the convention in RN is to use self-closing tags for images, like `<Image ... />`