# Load dynamic assets in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

How can I achieve this in react-native

`require("../images/vehicles/" + this.state.proccessedFirstData.make + ".png")`

`make` is the object property that I need to access dynamically, I have been searching around and I am not finding any solution

I also tried

`const IMAGE = require("../images/vehicles/" + this.state.proccessedFirstData.make + ".png")` and its not working

Comment: You cannot concat variables in require path. Actually you can but it is not recommended for as it can reduce the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RN bundler is static so you have to import all the resources at compile time.

You can still have a semi dynamic load:

```
const car1 = require('<path>')
const car2 = require('<path>')
const cars = {car1, car2}

<image source={cars[this.state.car]}>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS require statements are resolved at bundle time (when the JS bundle is calculated). Therefore it's not supported to put variable expression as an argument for `require`.

In case of requiring resources it's even more trickier. When you have `require('./someimage.png')`, React Native packager will locale required image and it will be then bundled together with the app so that it can be used as a "static" resource when your app is running (in fact in dev mode it won't bundle the image with your app but instead the image will be served from the server, but this doesn't matter in your case).

If you want to use random image as a static resource you'd need to tell your app to bundle that image. You can do it in a few ways:

1) Add it as a static asset of your app, then reference to it with `<Image src={{uri:'name_of_the_image_in_assets.png'}}/>` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907218/react-native-use-variable-for-image-file/33917557#33917557) is how you can add it to the native iOS app)

2) Require all the images upfront statically. Sth in a form of:

```
var randomImages = [
    require('./image1.png'),
    require('./image2.png'),
    require('./image3.png'),
    ...
];
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
<Image src={randomImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImages.length)]}/>
```

3) Use network image with `<Image src={{uri:'http://i.imgur.com/random.jpg'}}/>`

[ref from this link -- thanks @kzzzf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907218/react-native-use-variable-for-image-file/33917557#33917557)

Comment: I get an error: `require` expect exactly 1 string literal argument

Comment: sorry it was not working @NtiyisoRikhotso i have updated my answer please check it