# Passing Image source to a Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-component

I have a file main.js that calls a component Home like

```
 <Home width = {width} }/>
```

And my home component has an Image like

```
class Home extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style = {{width: this.props.width/2,height:this.props.width/2 ,
                borderWidth:0.5,borderColor:'#dddddd'}}>
               <View style = {{flex : 1}}>
               <Image 
               style = {{flex:1,width:null,height:null,resizeMode:'cover'}}
               source = {require(this.props.source)} >
               </Image>
               </View>
               <View style ={{flex:1 , alignItems:'flex-start', 
               justifyContent:'space-evenly', paddingLeft: 10}}>
               <Text style = {{fontSize:14,color:'#b63838'}}> 5 bedroom </Text>
               <Text style = {{fontSize:12 , fontWeight:'bold'}}>North York</Text>
               <Text style = {{fontSize:12 , fontWeight:'bold'}}>$4000</Text>
               </View>
                </View>
        );
    }
}
export default Home;
```

The image is store locally in an asset folder which can be accessed by 
`require('../assets/Images/Houses/house6.jpeg');`

My component has to be called multiple times using different images.
How can I pass the image path to the Home component.

```
<Home width = {width} source = ??????/>
```

Comment: You have already accessed `this.props.source` in your home component. The only thing you have to write is `<Home width = {width} source ="../assets/Images/Houses/house6.jpeg" />`

Comment: Sorry that actually gives me an error saying require{this.props.source} is an invalid call

Comment: `<Image style = {{flex:1,width:null,height:null,resizeMode:'cover'}} source = {this.props.source} ></Image>`
Remove the require function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already accessed `this.props.source` in your home component. 
As below mentioned export your images in a file to be imported in any component.

Update :

```
const images = {
    houseImage: require(‘../assets/Images/Houses/house6.jpeg’)
};


export default images;
```

Home component

```
import Images from ‘@assets/images’;

<Image style = {{flex:1,width:null,height:null,resizeMode:'cover'}}  source={Images.houseImage} />
```

Comment: Yeh I tired doing as you said but I still get the invalid props "source" error

Comment: I followed this article to load local assets and it helped out .
https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/react-native-tips-and-tricks-2-0-managing-static-assets-with-absolute-paths/

Comment: Ok.Updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
class ParentClass extends Component {
   construct() {
      this.state = {
         images : [require('../path/to/image1.png'), require('../path/to/image2.png')]
      };
   }

   render = () => {
      // Iterate through this one...
      return(<Home width={width} source={this.state.images[i]});
   }
}
```

You can't pass something dynamic to a require() function.
Read on further here: [react native use variable for image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907218/react-native-use-variable-for-image-file)