# Error using useState on Image Address with React Native

Tags: react-native

I am having a problem when I try to concatenate the address of a local image with a value stored in useState.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Button, Text } from 'native-base';
import styles from './DescobertaGravidezStyle';
import Header from '../../../components/principalComponents/header/Header';

export default () => {
  const [bg, setBg] = useState('Green');

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <ImageBackground
        source={require(`../../../img/bg/bg${bg}.png`)}
        style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
      ></ImageBackground>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> You have to provide a physical address of the path not in the state or
>   a variable.
>  Just because react native bundles it before running
>   the code
>  Furthermore if you want to use it from a variable then
>   make a component which returns the path when called.

More you can read here :- [react native use variable for image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907218/react-native-use-variable-for-image-file)