# Reactjs: How to import an image from a variable path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I am relatively new to Reactjs so I might be missing something obvious:

I have a component (DisplayFlags.js) that displays country flags along with country names depending on a previously chosen continent. I have everything set up: all possible flag images exist locally, I also have a js object called 'myCountries' that maps each continent to its countries, and each country to its name + local flag image name. Here is a part of it:

```
const myCountries ={
    "north-america": {
        "US": {
            "name": "United States",
            "picPath": "flag-of-United-States.png"
        },
        "UM": {
            "name": "United States Minor Outlying Islands",
            "picPath": "flag-of-United-States-Minor-Outlying-Islands.png"
        },
        "CA": {
            "name": "Canada",
            "picPath": "flag-of-Canada.png"
        },
        "MX": {
            "name": "Mexico",
            "picPath": "flag-of-Mexico.png"
        },
//etc
},
"south-america":{
  "AR": {
            "name": "Argentina",
            "picPath": "flag-of-Argentina.png"
        },
        "BO": {
            "name": "Bolivia",
            "picPath": "flag-of-Bolivia.png"
        },
//etc
}
}
```

What I am planning to do: loop through all the countries of a previously selected continent, and pass the "name" and "picPath" as props to another component, SingleCountry.js, who in turn displays them.
My problem is with importing: I usually just write (example):

```
import randomImage from '../../img/icons/some-image-name.png'
```

And then use randomImage as the src of an img element in my component. In this case, is there a way to import an image from a path that is passed in props?
Something like:

```
import flagImage from "../../img/flags/" + this.props.picPath
```

I understand that the above doesn't work because imports work outside of a component, and they don't have access to any kind of props. Can I import inside a component?
Or should I totally drop this and import images in bulk in DisplayFlag.js then pass images one by one into SingleCountry.js?

Comment: Check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907218/react-native-use-variable-for-image-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

Using `import` for browser and `nodejs`

```
const picture = (await import(`../path/to/file/${this.props.picPath}`)); // this is async
```

Using `require` for browser and `nodejs`

```
const picture = require(`../path/to/file/${this.props.picPath}`); // this is sync
```

Using `readFileSync` from `fs` only for `nodejs`

```
const fs = require('fs')
// or: import fs from 'fs'

const file = fs.readFileSync(`../path/to/file/${this.props.picPath}`).toString()
```

Using `readFile` from `fs` only for `nodejs`

```
const fs = require('fs')
// or: import fs from 'fs'
const file = (await fs.readFile(`../path/to/file/${this.props.picPath}`)).toString()
```

**Tip #1:**

When you using require, it only can handle json and js files, but when you using import, it can handle svg, and other stuff.
But you can apply some trick like:

```
// in tsconfig.json
"include": [
    "./declarations.d.ts",
],
```

```
// in declaration.d.ts
declare module '*.png';
```

**Tip #2:**

When you wanna import images like `png`, you should be define how it work with this:

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

**Tip #3**
In javascript you can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) using ``` `` ``` and `${}`.

```js
const name = "John"
console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
```

Comment: I ended up using require (2nd suggestion above), while not having to make any module edits to handle jpg, etc. I guess it's because I started from create-react-app, so it's already handled for me. Thank you!

Comment: As a follow up to anyone who might be looking at this: the above worked for me in development, but didn't work in production. As I don't know how to properly debug it, I ended up importing all flags to the component, as per another answer here.

Answer (score 5):

You could have a file import all the images like

```
//images/index.js

import image1 from './image1.png'
import image2 from './image2.png'
.
.
export default {
image1,
image2,
.
.
}
```

you can access images dynamically from the object exported from here

```
import images from './images/index.js'
images['image1'] 

// or dynamically
let name = 'image2'
images[name]
```

Answer (score 1):

What first coming to my head is to create stateless component which will take your flag object and show  tag with specific path. It won't import as react suggest but it will do the job :)
Instead if u really want use react approches you could use require instead of import, checkout below question, I think it will satisfying you:

[react native use variable for image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907218/react-native-use-variable-for-image-file)