# why image doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to feed image path through property `path` and render it. I have many images and I want to set the image in `runtime` so I cannot use pre `import` the image prior to rendering. But the image does not show.

**Error:** `cannot find module` (but path is correct)
but when I replace the varible `path` to actual path as `var imageName = require('./Assets/profpicjpg.jpg').default;` then image shows up, but I wanna use the variable `path` to feed the variable path data

**Rendering this**

```
import Profpic1 from './Components/Public-page/Profile-card';
function App() {
  
  return (

    
    <div className="App">
      
    <Profpic1
        path = './Assets/profpicjpg.jpg'
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**Function** (this is in a different page)

```
export default function Profpic1 ({path})
  {
      
    var imageName = require(path).default;
    return ( 
<div>
   
   <img src={imageName} />
    </div>
 )}
```

Comment: All React component names must start with a capital letter. If you start a component name with a lowercase letter, it will be treated like a built-in element like a <div> or a <span> .   So use `Profpic1 ` instead of `profpic1 `

Comment: @kiranvj now an error pops up `cannot find module`. but when I replace the varible `path` to actual path as `var imageName = require('./Assets/profpicjpg.jpg').default`; then image shows up, but I wanna use the variable `path` to feed the variable path data.

Comment: [This will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33917557/7704650)

Comment: Can you move the assets folder to `public` folder and access the image like  `<img src={path} />` . Path in this case will be  `/Assets/profpicjpg.jpg` .   `./` changed to `/`

Comment: @kiranvj Then an error pops up `./src/Components/Public-page/Assets/profpicjpg.jpg
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory`

Comment: Move assets folder to `/public/Assets`  public folder will be outside `src`. Refer image like `/Assets/profpicjpg.jpg` in your component